# Power BI Trying to find a way to intersect two lines with a What If parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I'm experimenting with forecasting and discovering that Power BI's forecast options can't do what I want.

I am looking at the average of receipts issued for a company per month. The forecast feature of Power BI can only take into account an assumption based on historical production rates to predict the next period, in this case, the next 12 months:

[image]

However, the pandemic caused a sudden drop in issuance of receipts due to lockdowns and distancing restrictions, limiting capacity to issue receipts. You can see that refelcted in the line graph above.

So, I'm trying to determine a forecast of pent-up demand for receipts. The way I did this is to apply the following formula which looks at the average number of receipts issued every month and adds to it the difference between last month's average and the actual number of receipts issued. The result is the expected pent up demand for receipts. The difference between that expected pent up demand and the next months actual number of receipts issued becomes the next month's expected pent up demand, and this repeats for every month.

The result is this:

[image]

Where the solid purple line is the number of receipts issued per month (same as the blue line in the first line chart), the yellow dotted line is the forecasted number of receipts issued, the dotted orange line is the forecasted pent up demand up to the current date, and the dotted purple line is the forecasted pent up demand for the next year.

In other words:

```
(Dotted Yellow line) Receipts Issued Forecast = 
VAR Forecast =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Estimate[Receipts issued]),
    DATEADD(dimDate[Date], -1, YEAR)
)*'Production Rate %'[Production Rate % Value]
RETURN
IF(
    YEAR(MAX(dimDate[Date]))>YEAR(TODAY()),
    Forecast,
    SUM(Estimate[Receipts issued])
)

(Solid Purple Line) Receipts Issued = Estimate[Receipts Issued]

(Dotted Purple Line) Projected Estimated Demand = IF(DAY(TODAY()) <> 1, CALCULATE(SUM(Estimate[Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022)]), FILTER(Estimate, Estimate[Start of Month] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,DAY(TODAY())))), CALCULATE(SUM(Estimate[Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022)]), FILTER(Estimate, Estimate[Start of Month] >= TODAY())))

(Dotted Orange Line) Estimated Demand = CALCULATE(SUM(Estimate[Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022)]), FILTER(Estimate, Estimate[Start of Month] <= TODAY()))

Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022) = 
VAR DayInRow = CALCULATE(MAX([Start of Month]))
VAR tmpTbl =
FILTER(
       'Estimate'
       ,'Estimate'[Start of Month]<=DayInRow 
)
                    
VAR finalTable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        tmpTbl
        ,"PPTsIssuedPreviousRow"
                ,VAR previouStartOfMonth = 
                    DATEADD('Estimate'[Start of Month],-1, Month)
                RETURN
                            CALCULATE(
                                    SUM('Estimate'[Receipts issued])
                                    ,ALL('Estimate') -- to excude the row context
                                    ,previouStartOfMonth 
                            )
        ,"multiplication"
                ,[AvgYearlyReceiptsIssued (Excl 2020-2022)]*[AvgPercentageOfReceiptsIssuedThisMonth (Excl 2020-2022)]
           )
VAR result = SUMX(finalTable,[multiplication]- [PPTsIssuedPreviousRow])   
RETURN
ROUND(result,2)
```

As we can see, prior to the pandemic, the pent-up demand was trending negative until 2018 because the company was issuing more receipts than the average, but pent up demand was starting to build since... and skyrocketed since the pandemic.

The yellow dotted line can be manipulated by the slider, which multiples the forecast by a production rate chosen by the user through a what if parameter. The idea behind this is to find the percentage by which the production rate of receipt issuance need to increase to reduce the forecasted pent up demand... the goal being to allow the user to play with the slider to find what point in the timeline they are comfortable with in finding that cross section.

As is, The yellow line works with the slider as expected. However, I'm not sure how to go about applying the slider to the dotted purple line to create the cross-section.

While the yellow line can be increased on the production rate in the slider, the dotted purple line needs to inversely decrease, starting with the first month, by the number of predicted receipts issued as a result of the boosted production rate.

I've tried modifying my code for the dotted purple line as follows:

```
Projected Estimated Demand = 
VAR Forecast2 = CALCULATE(SUM(Estimate[Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022)]), FILTER(Estimate, Estimate[Start of Month] >= TODAY())) - [Receipts Issued Forecast]
VAR DayInRow = CALCULATE(MAX([Start of Month]))
VAR __date = TODAY()
VAR __year = YEAR(__date)
VAR __day = DAY(__date)
VAR __month = MONTH(__date)
VAR todaysdate = DATE(__year,__month-1,__day)
VAR tmpTbl =
    FILTER(
           'Estimate'
           ,Estimate[Start of Month] >= todaysdate
    )
                        
VAR finalTable = 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            tmpTbl
            ,"PPTsIssuedPreviousRow"
                    ,VAR previouStartOfMonth = 
                        DATEADD('Estimate'[Start of Month],-1, Month)
                    RETURN
                                CALCULATE(
                                        SUM('Estimate'[Receipts issued])
                                        ,ALL('Estimate') -- to excude the row context
                                        ,previouStartOfMonth 
                                )
            ,"multiplication"
                    ,[AvgYearlyReceiptsIssued (Excl 2020-2022)]*[AvgPercentageOfReceiptsIssuedThisMonth (Excl 2020-2022)]
            ,"ReceiptsForecast"
                    ,Estimate[Receipts Issued Forecast]
            ,"ReceiptsEstDemandPreviousRow"
                    ,VAR previouStartOfMonth = 
                        DATEADD('Estimate'[Start of Month],-1, Month)
                    RETURN
                                CALCULATE(
                                        SUM(Estimate[Demand Estimate (Excl 2020-2022)])
                                        ,ALL('Estimate') -- to excude the row context
                                        ,previouStartOfMonth 
                                )
               )
VAR result = SUMX(finalTable, [ReceiptsEstDemandPreviousRow]-[ReceiptsForecast])
VAR Forecast = ROUND(result,2)
RETURN

IF(
   SUM(Estimate[Receipts issued]) = BLANK(),
   Forecast,
   Estimate[Estimated Demand]
)
```

However, the problem is that the dotted purple line is fluctuating far too aggressively, which tells me that it isn't iterating the way it should.

[image]

The orange line increases at a rate of about 100k per month. The yellow line has a minimum issuance value of around 1M so the purple line, by any reasonable measure, shouldn't be bouncing back up at all and should be on a steady rate of decline month over month.

Can anyone help me figure out how to correct the formula for the purple line?

There is way too much data to share here directly, but the project file is accessible: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzogtK22NcRn-IxoNqi7IElbnJ7odMHB/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, sounds like you need to update the measure for the dotted purple line to remove the gap that appears between the dotted yellow line with the production.

In pseudocode:

```
[Purple] = [Current logic for purple] - ([Yellow at user selected production rate %] - [Yellow at production rate of 0%])
```

Comment: There is no gap.  Your formula yields no difference in results. The projected Estimated Demand should no crater the way it is right now.